# Split String Search Pattern Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, split

In Java you can split a string by doing something like this.

```
data.split("245 10 ");
```

And in objective-c

```
[data componentSeparatedByString:@"245 10 "];
```

However in Java you can also specify any character in the string pattern etc.

```
data.split("245 1\\d ");
```

The \d represents any character is there a way to do this in objective-c.
Thanks. I have already tried \d however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) provides `componentsSeparatedByRegex:` that does exactly what you are looking for.

Otherwise you may consider using [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to split your string:

```
NSString *regex = @""; //your regex
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex]; 

if( [predicate evaluateWithObject:string]) 
    NSLog(@"matches");
else
    NSLog(@"does not match");
```